# Win2D: How to draw a center image inside a circle scalable

Tags: c#, win2d

i'm trying to draw a scaled image inside a circle using Win2D in c# and i'm failing on doing this.

My tries are for example:

```
    CanvasBitmap image;
    bool resourcesLoaded = false;
    public Other() {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    void canvasControl_Draw(CanvasControl sender, CanvasDrawEventArgs args) {
        if( resourcesLoaded ) {
            var halfWidth = sender.ActualWidth / 2;
            var halfHeight = sender.ActualHeight / 2;

            double displayScaling = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi / 96.0;
            double pixelWidth = halfWidth * displayScaling;
            double pixelHeight = halfHeight * displayScaling;

            var scaleEffect = new ScaleEffect() {
                Source = image,
                Scale = new Vector2() {
                    X = ( float ) ( pixelHeight / image.Size.Height ),
                    Y = ( float ) ( pixelHeight / image.Size.Height ),
                }
            };
            var blurEffect = new GaussianBlurEffect() {
                Source = scaleEffect,
                BlurAmount = 5f
            };

            args.DrawingSession.FillCircle( new System.Numerics.Vector2() { X = ( float ) halfWidth, Y = (float) halfHeight },
              (float) halfHeight/2,
              new CanvasImageBrush( sender, blurEffect ) {
                  SourceRectangle = new Rect(0,0, scaleEffect.GetBounds(sender).Width, scaleEffect.GetBounds( sender ).Height)
              } );
        }
    }
    private void canvasControl_CreateResources(CanvasControl sender, Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.CanvasCreateResourcesEventArgs args) {
        args.TrackAsyncAction( CreateResources( sender ).AsAsyncAction() );
    }
    private async Task CreateResources(CanvasControl sender) {
        image = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync( canvasControl, new Uri( "ms-appx:///Imgs/test.jpg" ) );
        resourcesLoaded = true;
        sender.Invalidate();
    }
```

And what happen is that the image seems to be draw in X=0 and Y=0 position of the window (the canvas uses all window), so my circle is in the middle of the window then only a bit of the image is paint and i wanted that my image be placed on the center of the circle.

So the questions are:
- is my scale correctly done? why divide by 96? can i read this from the system?
- is it possible to blur only the edges of the image?
- and how can i draw my image in the center of the circle?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i managed to correct my problem, first the answers to may questions are:

- is my scale correctly done?

in the next sample code now they are (the scale must use both, with and height)

- why divide by 96? can i read this from the system?

96 is the DPI, so we need to get the current DPI used by your system, we can call CanvasControl.Dpi to find out

- and how can i draw my image in the center of the circle?

well is better to show the code to answer this one, but basically the idea is to do everything inside a CanvasCommandList and then draw the CanvasCommandList wherever desired on the window:

```
    CanvasCommandList cl;
    CanvasBitmap image;
    bool resourcesLoaded = false;
    private void canvasControl_CreateResources(CanvasControl sender, Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.CanvasCreateResourcesEventArgs args) {
        args.TrackAsyncAction( CreateResources( sender ).AsAsyncAction() );
    }
    private async Task CreateResources(CanvasControl sender) {
        image = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync( canvasControl, new Uri( "ms-appx:///Imgs/test.jpg" ) );
        int ratio = 6;
        var newImgWidth = image.Size.Width / ratio;
        var newImgHeight = image.Size.Height / ratio;

        double displayScaling = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi / sender.Dpi;
        double pixelWidth = newImgWidth * displayScaling;
        double pixelHeight = newImgHeight * displayScaling;

        cl = new CanvasCommandList( sender );
        using( CanvasDrawingSession clds = cl.CreateDrawingSession() ) {
            var scaleEffect = new ScaleEffect() {
                Source = image,
                Scale = new Vector2() {
                    X = ( float ) ( pixelWidth / image.Size.Width ),
                    Y = ( float ) ( pixelHeight / image.Size.Height ),
                }
            };
            var blurEffect = new GaussianBlurEffect() {
                Source = scaleEffect,
                BlurAmount = 5f
            };

            //don't now why but we need to do this in order to have the correct bounds size
            clds.DrawImage( blurEffect, 0, 0, new Rect( 0, 0, newImgWidth, newImgHeight ), 0.05f );
            //now draw the circle
            clds.FillCircle( ( float ) newImgWidth / 2, ( float ) newImgHeight / 2,
              ( float ) ( newImgWidth > newImgHeight ? newImgHeight : newImgWidth ) / 2,
              new CanvasImageBrush( sender, scaleEffect ) {
                  SourceRectangle = new Rect( 0, 0, newImgWidth, newImgHeight )
              } );
        }
        resourcesLoaded = true;
    }

    void canvasControl_Draw(CanvasControl sender, CanvasDrawEventArgs args) {
        if( resourcesLoaded ) {
            //cell (0,0)
            args.DrawingSession.DrawImage( cl,
                0,
                0 );
            args.DrawingSession.DrawRectangle( new Rect(
                0, 0,
                cl.GetBounds( sender ).Width, cl.GetBounds( sender ).Height ), Windows.UI.Colors.Red, 3 );
            //cell (0,1)
            args.DrawingSession.DrawImage( cl,
                ( float ) ( sender.ActualWidth - cl.GetBounds( sender ).Width ),
                ( float ) ( 0 ) );
            args.DrawingSession.DrawRectangle( new Rect(
                ( sender.ActualWidth - cl.GetBounds( sender ).Width ), 0,
                cl.GetBounds( sender ).Width, cl.GetBounds( sender ).Height ), Windows.UI.Colors.Green, 3 );
            //cell (1,0)
            args.DrawingSession.DrawImage( cl, ( float ) ( 0 ),
                ( float ) ( sender.ActualHeight - cl.GetBounds( sender ).Height ) );
            args.DrawingSession.DrawRectangle( new Rect(
                ( 0 ),
                ( sender.ActualHeight - cl.GetBounds( sender ).Height ),
                cl.GetBounds( sender ).Width, cl.GetBounds( sender ).Height ), Windows.UI.Colors.Yellow, 3 );
            //cell (1,1)
            args.DrawingSession.DrawImage( cl,
                ( float ) ( sender.ActualWidth - cl.GetBounds( sender ).Width ),
                ( float ) ( sender.ActualHeight - cl.GetBounds( sender ).Height ) );
            args.DrawingSession.DrawRectangle( new Rect(
                ( sender.ActualWidth - cl.GetBounds( sender ).Width ),
                ( sender.ActualHeight - cl.GetBounds( sender ).Height ),
                cl.GetBounds( sender ).Width, cl.GetBounds( sender ).Height ), Windows.UI.Colors.Orange, 3 );
        }
    }
```

This draws 4 circle images correctly in each corner of the window as expected and desired, the only problem that i think that is a bug probably, is that if you only draw the Circle in the CanvasCommandList the bounds of this are half of what is expected, for this i need to draw the all image faded only to ensure that the bounds are correctly as expected... maybe there is a better solution but this is the best one that i found.